# Alternate to border for TABLE

Tags: css, html

Want to write CSS style class for TABLE element to get a grid-like look, just how it used to appear in old days with attribute 'border=1'.

If I have it defined in a class, the style would only apply to the TABLE where I intend to present the data in a grid format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

1) Assign the table you want to style an `id` (below i gave it the id `my-styled-table`

2) Style the table however you like to

- Note, if you wan't many tables to have the same design, use a `class` instead of an `id`

```css
#my-styled-table {
  border: 2px solid black; /* The whole table get a border */
}

#my-styled-table th {
  border: 1px solid black; /* The header columns gets a border */
}
```

```html
<table id="my-styled-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data 1a</td>
    <td>Data 1b</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data 2a</td>
    <td>Data 2b</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data 3a</td>
    <td>Data 3b</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data 4a</td>
    <td>Data 4b</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it.